# Behaviour of the [5,2] extended ternary Hamming code

Tags: coding-theory

A received word using this code will have $3^{5-2}=27$ cosets:

if no error has occurred, the coset leader is 00000;

if only one error has occurred, then the coset leader is one of the ten possible weight-1 error words, right?

> So this leaves us with $16$ cosets remaining, corresponding to
>   $2$$5\choose2$$=20$ possible weight-$2$ error words. In this case, how
>   are the error words distributed among the different cosets? Some
>   cosets will clearly contain just one error word, implying that
>   this code can correct some two-bit errors. Which contradicts the
>   theorem saying that a code of minimum distance 4 (this one) can
>   correct up to one error!! So where have I gone wrong?

Comment: A linear code of minimum distance 4 can correct all one-bit errors. That doesn't preclude being able to correct some two-bit errors, it just can't correct *all* of them. There doesn't seem to be a contradiction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a total of 40 vectors of weight two. Ten ways to select the two non-zero positions, and two non-zero values for both of the non-zero components.
$$
40={5\choose 2} (3-1)^2.
$$

Comment: Ah, yes of course, thanks! I promise that this is my final question on this topic http://math.stackexchange.com/q/380438/21813, if you can spare a bit of time. I really appreciate your input and answers.